# WINAPI/C++: mouse hover over any child doesn't work - what can be the reason?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to catch mouse hovering over the buttons in my window, which I'm programming using plain C++14 in MSVS19 and WinAPI. Here's the code snippet and some context:

- isTracking is defined as bool earlier
- hBox is a button created in WM_CREATE using CreateWindowW

```
    hBox = CreateWindowW(WC_BUTTON, L"TEST BOX", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 300, 250, 100, 33, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTN10, NULL, NULL);
```

- hWnd is a handle to window that a CALLBACK WndProc function receives

  ```
      case  WM_MOUSEMOVE:
  {
      HWND hTrack = hBox;
      if (!isTracking) {
          TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = {};
          tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
          tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
          tme.hwndTrack = hTrack;
          tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
          TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
          isTracking = true;
      }
          break;
  }

  case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
  {
      OutputDebugStringW(L"HOVER\n");
      MessageBox(nullptr, L"Entered", L"Info", MB_OK);
      break;
  }

  case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
  {
      isTracking = false;
      MessageBox(nullptr, L"Left", L"Info", MB_OK);
      break;

  }
  ```

And it doesn't work.

However when I set hTrack to hWnd - it detects hovering over main window area (but not over any of the children) and creates message boxes.

I've tried hTrack = GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_BUTN10) too - but it doesn't work either for that element or any other. Only hWnd itself gets any reaction from the program - but I want to detect hovering over specific buttons and other UI elements.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly, but there is a main window and there is a second window (`hBox`). You are trying to move and track mouse in `hBox` which isn't happening. What I can think of (can be incorrect though) is that `hBox` isn't the top level window (or isn't active, not sure the correct phrase for that) because of which the mouse isn't being tracked.

Comment: From reading the documentation it seems that the messages are sent to the window you're tracking. I.e. in your case the events are sent to `hBox`.

Comment: The documentation for [`TRACKMOUSEEVENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-trackmouseevent) has the following on the `dwFlags` member: *"`TME_HOVER` \[...\] This flag is ignored if the mouse pointer is not over the specified window or area."* I'm not convinced that this is accurate, though if it is then that's likely what's causing your issues. I find that a bit hard to believe, though, as that would essentially mean that there's no way to use `TrackMouseEvent` for a child window without subclassing that child window.

Comment: @IInspectable That is exactly what you would have to do. Subclass the button to intercept its own `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages to trigger hover/leave tracking while the mouse is over the button.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it using your code, and I succeeded in implementing the functionality you wanted.
Maybe you are using the message callback incorrectly, you can refer to my code.

```
BOOL TestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
switch (pMsg->message)
{
    case  WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        HWND hTrack = hBox;
        if (!isTracking) {
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = {};
            tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
            tme.hwndTrack = hTrack;
            tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
            TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
            isTracking = true;
        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
    {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"HOVER\n");
        ::MessageBox(nullptr, L"Entered", L"Info", MB_OK);
        break;
    }

    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
        isTracking = false;
        //::MessageBox(nullptr, L"Left", L"Info", MB_OK);
        break;

    }

}
return CDialogEx::TestDlg(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: interesting - it works when I just send the 'MSG msg' variable to a separate function like you do - but when I do it the usual way through TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage which then sends it to the generic WndProc - it doesn't work even if the code is literally the same. I guess WndProc somehow messes with HWND forcing MOVE/HOVER/LEAVE actions to be local only to the parent window? And what would be the solution - other than using a separate function for solving this issue?

Comment: Hi,I suggest you can use SendMessage/PostMessage to send a MOVE/HOVER/LEAVE message and respond locally